# I can't serve css files ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core

I'm using dotnetcore and ASP MVC.
The problem is that I don't know how to serve correctly my css and images files.
Here you can see the file structure:

[image: file structure]

Here is the Shared layout's head.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Galeria de comics">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Galeria de comics</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/wwwroot/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/wwwroot/css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header"></header>
        @RenderBody()

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm called this layout in a View.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Libro comic detalle";
}
```

What's the problem?
The problem is that the CSS files aren't serve so I can't see the styles.
Any solition?

Comment: You are getting 404 for css files?

Comment: Yes, I am. How I fix that?

Comment: Enable serving static content on IIS. If you having troubles with other static files it could be IIS.

Comment: I'm doing this localy.

Comment: you have IIS localy to. Or at least IIS express

Comment: I have fixed it. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Seems I miss the href attribute's content. You should skip the `wwwroot` folder since the static files are served as `http://app/css/cssFileName`. Example: `http://yoursite.com/css/main.css`, same with images and js files.

Here I fixed the problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/main.css">
```

If you want to know more [visit this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)